# bash syntax error near unexpected token `(' when using parentheses in wildcard in script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, wildcard

I'm trying to run this script:

```
mkdir a
cd a
touch a1, a2, a_
ls ./a!(_)
echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nls ./a!(_)\n' >> run.sh
chmod a+x run.sh
./run.sh
```

The `ls` line prints the output as expected (`./a1,  ./a2,`), but the script fails with:

```
./run.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./run.sh: line 2: `ls ./a!(_)'
```

Is there any way to use parentheses in a bash script without using `find` or `for`?

Comment: [here?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494561/how-to-escape-parenthesis-in-bash-rmdir)

Comment: @GuinNess, ...btw, consider avoiding `.sh` extensions, *particularly* for bash scripts (which are not `sh` scripts). In general, UNIX commands don't have extensions (you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`; similarly, while a Python *library* will end in `.py`, a Python *script* installed in `/usr/bin/` or such typically won't).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable `bash`'s `extglob` option with `shopt -s extglob` to use the negation pattern.

Change the `echo` line to

```
printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'shopt -s extglob' 'ls ./a!(_)' > run.sh
```

You can disable extended globbing afterwards with `shopt -u extglob`.

Related:

- [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) (Bash manual)

Comment: `echo -e` is innately unreliable -- whether it works (even in bash) depends on both compile-time and runtime-configurable options (`shopt -s extglob` when `set -o posix` is active, and `echo -e` will emit `-e` on output; either environment variables or compile-time flags can do the same). Using `printf` is much more reliable (working not just on all bash configurations, but also with standards-compliant `/bin/sh` implementations).

Comment: In this case: `printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'shopt -s extglob' 'ls ./a!(_)'`; easier-to-read, too, since each line becomes one argument.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Agreed, replaced `echo` with `printf`.